# Python regex get (any) last word in string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string

My goal is to get the last word of a string, no matter what the word is.

With a lot of trials and error I got kinda lucky with the following code, because instead of \w+ I tried \W+ and got a result I could work with.

But my actual code (the one you don't see here) is kinda messy, so my question is; What is the right compile regex to use to get the last word, or two words?

Thanks in advance!

```
import re

var = ' hello my name is eddie   '

r = re.compile(r'\S+\W+$')
r2 = r.findall(var)
print(r2)

#result ['eddie   ']
```

Comment: Like this? `(\S+)\s*$` https://regex101.com/r/BcF2vb/1

Comment: or `var.strip().split(" ")[-1]`, and `[-2:]` if you need 2 words.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
import re
var = ' hello my name is eddie   '
r_last_word = re.compile(r'\S+(?=\s*$)')
r_last_but_one = re.compile(r'\S+(?=\s+\S+\s*$)')
print(r_last_word.findall(var))
print(r_last_but_one.findall(var))
```

Results:

```
['eddie']
['is']
```

See [proof](https://tio.run/##dY7LCsIwEEX3/YpZCEksdOO6@BFuCyGakQ5MHkxSpV8fu7CggrsL99xHXuuc4qk1CjlJBcHu4QRGUDAjc4KwQnQBgQqg94QAoDqx7Eq1zyR@QwWHWwqZGLWo6dLr8ziV48Eos4PXpdoU8R/bb2JPZKFY9cfAcKfoHbPefpkf/937jbT2Ag).

`\S+(?=\s*$)` - one or more non-whitespace characters that may have optional whitespaces after up to the end of string.

`\S+(?=\s+\S+\s*$)` - one or more non-whitespace characters that may have one or more whitespace characters, one or more non-whitespace characters and then optional whitespaces after up to the end of string.